Spectral properties of Ruelle transfer operator
Consider a compact metric space $(X,d)$, a continuous surjective map $T:X \to X$ of finite degree and the space of continuous functions $C(X)$ equipped with the supremum norm. Also, consider only (for brevity) the (bounded) transfer operator $L: C(X)\to C(X)$, $$Lf(x)=\sum_{T(y)=x} f(y).$$ What can be said about the spectrum of $L$? Also, can it happen that $L$ is bounded from below? It feels more possible if $T$ is some sort of expanding map. Thanks!
